# How to mark dynamically initialized globals as "discardable if unused" in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, global

I have some globals like

```
FARPROC const f = GetProcAddress(...);
```

Is there any way to urge the compiler or linker to discard them (and related initialization code) if it is determined the code is unused at link-time (like with [`/Gy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gy-enable-function-level-linking) and [`/OPT:REF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations))?

Comment: Put each one in its own object file and it’ll get discarded if unused.

Comment: `/Gw` looks useful (off by default) _"...causes the compiler to package global data in individual COMDAT sections...."_ ... _"...in order to exclude unreferenced global data..."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gw-optimize-global-data?view=msvc-160

Comment: @RichardCritten: I'm trying that but it's not working. At least I still see the (unique) procedure name I'm giving it still embedded in the optimized binary. Is it working locally for you guys? (Also, what's with the downvote?)

Comment: Release build ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes (obviously - that's why I said it was an optimized binary). Is it working for yourself?

Comment: I think `/Gw` is only for constant initialization (see [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140207025607/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/11/introducing-gw-compiler-switch.aspx)).

Comment: @RichardCritten: I figured out out, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems **[`__declspec(selectany)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/selectany)** does this, even without passing [`/Gw`](https://web.archive.org/web/20140207025607/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/11/introducing-gw-compiler-switch.aspx).

As an example, this program will only contain `GetTickCount_`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

FARPROC GetTickCount_ =
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "GetTickCount");

__declspec(selectany) FARPROC GetTickCount64_ =
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32.dll")), "GetTickCount64");

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: this program shouldn't have either since it has a `main` function

Comment: @M.M: Huh? I don't follow.

Comment: The compiler should be able to optimize immediately (as opposed to waiting for link-time optimization) since the variables are not used

Comment: also I am not sure how realistic this is, since if the variables are not exposed in headers then you should have marked them as `static`. And if they are in headers then the code will be different.

Comment: @M.M: Well, it isn't optimizing it. I don't get your complaint. I just gave a code sample. Do whatever you want with it. Put it into a header or a separate file, mark it as `static` or whatever. Nothing is preventing you from making it more complicated. I'm just illustrating the solution. Go wild with it. Nobody said you have to put these exact 11 lines into production.

Comment: `static` means the identifier is not visible to other translation units , therefore it is a different situation to when an identifier is shared amongst translation units .

Comment: @M.M: I know perfectly well what it means. I'm telling you **it does not make a difference in the binary**. The problem is still there just the same; it doesn't affect the problem in any way. Go try it out if you don't believe me.

Comment: What if you use a variable in a function, and then don't use the function? Will the var be removed?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: With constant initialization yes. With dynamic initialization, the initialization code gets removed, but I don't know if the variable itself gets removed; the binary still ends up bigger than having nothing else at all. It seems to result in a TLS section getting added for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform soluition, use `static` variables in template classes. They are discarded if unused, even if the initializer has side effects.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <std::nullptr_t = nullptr>
struct A
{
    inline static const int value = []{
        std::ios_base::Init init;
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
        return 42;
    }();
};

int main()
{
    // Nothing is printed, unless you uncomment following:
    // (void)A<>::value;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too and that hasn't worked for me either. Does it work for you when you try it?

Comment: @user541686 I'm not on Windows, so I can't try MSVC, but on Clang it does work. [gcc.godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zEvhW86zY) shows no assembly on MSVC for the initializer if the variable is unused, so I assume it's dicarded.

Comment: Okay actually this isn't quite what I want here. The problem is that the "unused"ness I'm talking about is determined at link-time, not compile-time. i.e. I have have a function inside that module that needs to reference the variable. But I might not call that function anywhere. And I want both get discarded in that case.

Comment: @user541686 I suggest adding this info to the question.